# Python ctypes.BigEndianStructure can't store a value

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I am in trouble with ctypes.BigEndianStructure. I can't get the value that I set to one the fields. My code is like this.

```
import ctypes
class MyStructure(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('fx', ctypes.c_uint, 7),
        ('fy', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1)
    ]

x = MyStructure()
```

It prints 0 as excepted:

```
print x.fy  # Prints 0
```

then I set a value to it but it still prints 0:

```
x.fy = 1
print x.fy  # Still prints 0
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I pasted your exact code and used Python 2.7.5 (32-bit).

Comment: More importantly, you should check the `ctypes.sizeof(MyStructure)` as it probably isn't what you expect.  The current definition is 5 bytes.  If you are trying to pack one byte, both `fx` and `fy` should be `c_ubyte`.  Using a different type starts a new packing.

Comment: Also works as is in Python 3.3 (64-bit).  Need more details to reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why what your doing doesn't work and it is certainly strange behavior. I think this alternative code works.

```
import ctypes
class MyStructure(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.fx=ctypes.c_uint(7)
        self.fy = ctypes.c_ubyte(1)

x = MyStructure()
x.fy = 7
print x.fy # prints 7
```

Or without the constructor::

```
import ctypes
class MyStructure(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    fx = ctypes.c_uint(7)
    fy = ctypes.c_ubyte(1)

x = MyStructure()
x.fy = 7
print x.fy # prints 7
```

I have personally never used the *fields* attribute so I can't speak to the odd behavior.

Comment: This code has a different meaning than the original.  The syntax the OP used is for bit-packing.  This code just declares a full int and ubyte in a non-standard way.  `_fields_` should be used or things like `ctypes.sizeof` won't work correctly (it returns zero).